# treeview content with a form link in C#

Tags: c#

```
TreeNode node1 = new TreeNode("firstC");
TreeNode node2 = new TreeNode("secondC");
TreeNode[] array = new TreeNode[] {node1, node2};
TreeNode treeNode = TreeNode("Root",array);
treeView1.Nodes.Add(treeNode);
```

I want to give a link to another Form, when someone click to 'firstC' it must open another form. I couldn't see TreeNode constructor about this. Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out the events. Easiest way to do this is open the property window and go to events (lightning icon in Visual Studio). Then double click within `nodemouseclick` or something like that. Then a function is automaticly created where you can open the form.

Within that function check if the node is that node.

```
void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender,  
    TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    if( e.node.text == "firstC" )
    {
     // Open dialog
    }
}
```

Events information
[Node mouseclick event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.treeview.nodemouseclick.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

```
   private void AddNodes()
    {
       TreeNode tn = new TreeNode() { Tag = Someform };
        //add nodes
        treeView1.NodeMouseClick += new TreeNodeMouseClickEventHandler(treeView1_NodeMouseClick);
    }
  void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
    {
        (e.Node.Tag as Form).Show();
    }
```